# Different between Android onResume(), onStart() and lifecycleScope

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have viewmodel call TestViewModel and a method call fetchDataFromDataSource() to call fetch data from the server, I used to call load data on **OnResume()** until I bump into **lifecycleScope**

I have tried to read more but didn't really get which is better.

```
class TestViewModel: Viewmodel() {

    fun fetchDataFromDataSource(){
       ....
    }
}




class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val viewModel: TestViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        // Is it best to call here 
         viewModel.fetchDataFromDataSource()
        }
    }
}

onResume(){
  super.onResume()
  // or is it best to call here 
         viewModel.fetchDataFromDataSource()
}
```

}

where is the best place to call fetchDataFromDataSource(),  is it in onResume() or lifecycleScope and what is the advantage lifecycleScope has over onResume() or onStart()

I know the view has rendered at onResume() so what benefit does lifecycleScope has over android lifecycle (onResume onCreate onStart...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repeatOnLifecycle` is similar to calling methods on the respective lifecycle events every time the Activity hits that state but with a quick access to the `lifecycleScope` which can launch a `coroutine`.

Example:

```kotlin
override fun onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    viewModel.fetchDataFromDataSource()
}
```

is equivalent to -

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity {

  init {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
           viewModel.fetchDataFromDataSource()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to load the data from `ViewModel` every time the user comes to foreground from background, use `onStart` or `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)`.

If you need to load the data everytime the `Activity` **resumes**, then use `onResume` or the lifecycleScope equivalent as shown above but if this is just a one-time op, consider using `onCreate`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am really confuse on what problem lifecycleScope  solved if I can call my function from onCreate() or onResume()... is there any advantages

Comment: There's not much difference apart from that it is a `suspend` function & was primarily created to collect the `Flow`s safely with a restartable behaviour. You can still use your functions in relevant lifecycle methods like `onResume` or `onStart`.